# Will I need a transit visa for Sri Lanka transit to Maldives UK citizen

Tags: visas, transit, uk-citizens, dxb

I am a UK citizen travelling from UK to the Maldives, with a stopover of 7 hours in Dubai, then a stopover in Sri Lanka of 9 hrs, will I need any visas?

Comment: @MichaelHampton says in the question UK citizen

Comment: @blackbird57 Ah, it was hidden in the title.

Comment: This might be best split into two questions - the answers for Dubai and Sri Lanka could well be different

Comment: @Gagravarr will I agree with you from a moderation perspective, I think one time/first time askers like the OP are supremely uninterested in finding answers to their question in 2-3 different places

Answer (score 3):

## Dubai layover

**No**, you don't need a visa if you have confirmed onward tickets and your stay is less than 24 hours.

## Sri Lanka layover

**Yes**, in your specific case you need a visa. Typically you wouldn't if your layover is less than 8 hours (provided you have confirmed onward tickets of course)

## Maldives stay

**Yes**, you need a visa but you can get one on arrival for 30 days

Emirates airlines has an IATA-Timatic based [web app](http://www.emirates.com/us/english/plan_book/essential_information/visa_passport_information/find_visa_requirements/visa_passport_information_results.aspx?NC=GB&NV=United+Kingdom&DC=MV&DV=Maldives&TC=LK%2cAE&TV=Sri+Lanka%2cUnited+Arab+Emirates&h=24386bfd7a43feeeed79412da53cbed79dbe28) to figure this stuff out
[image]

Comment: The asker said he had a 9 hour transit time in sri-lanka. So it seems like he does need to get a transit visa.

Comment: @PeterGreen nice catch ! updated